# Color grading software (Preferably free or part of Adobe CC) with individual color HSL controls (like Lightroom)

Tags: software-recommendation, color-correction, color-grading

Lightroom makes it very easy for me to stylize my photos with HSL controls which allow me to adjust the hue, saturation, and luminance of individual colors. What can I use to do this with my video?

Comment: What OS are you running? It's hard to give an answer without at least knowing that.

Comment: Mac OSX El Capitan @user1118321